# Jenkins remote API - wait for build to finish and get output?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-api

When using Jenkins CLI, I can use the `build` command  with options `-v` and `-s` to run a build, waiting for it to finish and printing its output.

Is there any way I can achieve the same result (wait for execution and get job output) with a single call to the REST API? I know this can be done by polling for build status until it finishes and then requesting its output, but I want to know if there is a straightforward option for short-running jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that somehow. But even if you do also you can't able to apply the same code for other jobs. There will be waiting period for the `next available executor` or some race conditions like this might happen. And holding the rest API for that long period is not gonna be a good option. And nobody suggests that.

So Instead of looking for the REST API, you can have an algorithm for polling itself. instead of every second, take results from the previous builds and process it and try to predict the near possible time and then poll. Like this kind of algorithms or else you can use `Jenkins build remaining time` also. Hope this makes sense.